# How to set up qt4 with cmake in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, qt4, clion

I'm currently trying to set up qt4 to work with cmake in the CLion IDE, however I'm having trouble specifying the install path. I'm running Ubuntu so I downloaded qt4 with `sudo apt install qt4-default`. Where does this install it to? How do I tell cmake where to find the package configuration files?

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(ContactClasses)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Contact.h Contact.cpp ContactList.h ContactList.cpp ContactFactory.h ContactFactory.cpp)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/share/qt4")

find_package(Qt4Core REQUIRED)

add_executable(Homework_6 ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(ContactClasses Qt4::Core)
```

I get this error when I try to reload it:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt4Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt4Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt4Core" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt4CoreConfig.cmake
    qt4core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt4Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt4Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt4Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specialized `FindQt4` module for that in `CMake` see its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindQt4.html).

You call it as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED QtCore)
add_executable(Homework_6 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Homework_6 PUBLIC Qt4::QtCore)
```